# cannot install qgis on ubuntu 23.10

Tags: ubuntu, qgis

installation fails with an error

```
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspatialite.so.8: undefined symbol: GEOSFrechetDistanceDensify_r
```

I use the official repository from the qgis manual

I trying to install qgis on ubuntu 23.10 and I expected it to work with the official qgis repository https://qgis.org/ubuntu

I tried installing from the ubuntu repo, version 3.28 no success

I tried installing other version like focal instead of mantic but that's not compatible